# WCF ServiceHost передача параметра

Tags: c#, wcf

Имеется следующая структура:

```
public class Starter
{
    public void Start()
    {
        var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceExchange), new Uri(uri));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServiceExchange)), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
    }
}
```

`ServiceExchange` описан так:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ создать объект(например список) в методе `Start` и передать его в `ServiceExchange`, который является контрактом, доступным клиентам? При этом, чтобы этот список мог обновляться как изнутри `ServiceExchange`, так и снаружи, в классе `Starter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У конструктора `ServiceHost` есть [перегрузка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms585487(v=vs.110).aspx), которая позволяет передать уже готовый экземпляр сервиса:

```
var someList = new List<SomeObject>();
var service = new ServiceExchange(someList);
var host = new ServiceHost(service, new Uri(uri));
```

Но поскольку вы собираетесь изменять список как внутри сервиса, так и снаружи, могут возникнуть проблемы с синхронизацией. Я бы порекомендовал инкапсулировать работу со списком в некий класс, в котором будут все необходимые методы, а также синхронизация доступа к списку (поскольку изменяться он будет все равно из разных потоков -- один поток сервиса и как минимум один поток приложения). А затем использовать этот класс из нужных мест.

Comment: в этом случае сервис будет являться синглетоном, или нет? Будет всегда использоваться один созданный нами экземпляр сервиса?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov да.

Comment: @Sleeeper не за что!